# How to get the endpoint of a line in Java given the midpoint and the other endpoint

Tags: java, math

I know how to do the maths on paper but I am struggling to work out how to take potential negative values into account.

Given 2 locations: endpoint(x1, y1) and midpoint(x2, y2)
Find the other endpoint location

Comment: Homework...? Mark it so.

Comment: @RickMangi homework tag is [deprecated see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated). @ MrSnare Can you shade more light with example and what your approach on paper and how its affecting your recent calculation with negative number?

Comment: Why do you think negative values is a problem?

Comment: It is not homework. It is minecraft project. I have 2 entity locations (lets call them "MrSnare" and "player"). If MrSnare's location and player's location are on a line where player's location is the midpoint. What is the other endpoint of the line.

Comment: Isn't this a simple math question?  What does it have to do with Java?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/98NaTuJ.png
Here is a diagram I drew. I know point A and B. I need to find point C which is the same distance from B that A is

Comment: If you have the diagram, puzzle it out for yourself.  It's not at all complicated.

Comment: I don't know how to do it in java

Comment: The same way you'd do it with pencil and paper.

Comment: @smit thanks for cluing me in :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Point2D endpoint; //defined elsewhere
Point2D midpoint; //defined elsewhere

Point2D otherend = new Point2D(endpoint.getX() + 2 * (midpoint.getX() - endpoint.getX()),
                               endpoint.getY() + 2 * (midpoint.getY() - endpoint.getY()));
```

(Sorry -- I made a bonheheaded mistake the first time.)

Comment: This is it. Thank you very much. I couldn't wrap my head around it

Comment: Whenever working with graphics or graphical problems, have graph paper handy. This question was really just a basic application of how lines work -- the distance formula is unnecessary as all we care about are the differences in x- and y-directions, and because we have a midpoint, we want to double those distances. The worry about negatives is, as it turns out, a non-issue, again because of how slope works. Anyway, glad I could help. (And in my haste, I made a couple really simple mistakes of my own.)

Answer (score 2):

I would comment, but my rep is too low. Without code it would be hard to tell. What you need to do is distinguish absolute distance between the two, determine direction based on whether the distance between the two is negative or positive, and do the math on that.

```
Example: x1 = 2, x2 = 0, y1 = 0, y2 = 0
   distance = -2x, 0y
   x2 - 2 = -2 = x3
   y3 = 0
```

Easier if you show us some code, but in other words just find the distance between x1 and x2, make that the distance between x2 and x3. Do the same for y's.

Comment: but if x2 = 3
x2 - x1 is 3 - 2 = 1
x3 should be 4 not 1

Comment: it would be 3 + 1 which = 4. It isn't x2 - x1, it is x2 + (x2-x1)

Comment: Oh ok. That's where I was failing so. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could use these two points to find the equation of the line(y=mx+b) and by finding the length of the line portion you know(Sqrt(x^2+y^2)) then draw the line in the positive x direction for the length you have found.

Comment: No need for square root.